# How to run same test class parallel in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, load

I create one test class and i want to run that class 10 times in same time with load test in VS 2017 in c#. I use chrome driver. When I run second instance first one is stop executing.

Comment: Please show the relevant code parts.

Comment: You should to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use while loop or for loop and run your same class 10 times